# Reposition partition on hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

Is there any way using CMD or under windows 7 to reposition  a partition (c:\ in my case] from the middle to the first sector on my HDD without losing the DATA it contains. Here is the the case in my computer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not "under Windows 7", no  - you can't move a partition while running an OS booted from that partition.

Use gparted, a FOSS tool. Download the ISO, burn it to CD, boot from the CD. You can find detailed instructions for using it all over the web, but it's pretty obvious.

Comment: You could also do that with Windows install disk and the `diskpart` tool, but it's not as user-friendly as GParted. **Always backup your files before messing with partitions and make partition table backup - just in case.** Moving partitions is safe in reliable in theory, but accidents happen.